# Rails Minitest crashing when tests fail

Tags: ruby-on-rails, minitest

Minitest crashes every time a test fails when I run `rails test` (Rails 5 and Ruby 2.4.2). For example, I forced a simple test to fail by switching the `assert` to `assert_not`:

```
Failure: TransactionTest#test_transaction_should_be_valid [/home/.../test/models/transaction_test.rb:11]: Expected true to be nil or false

/home/.../.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.2/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/test_unit/reporter.rb:70:in `method': undefined method `test_transaction_should_be_valid' for class `Minitest::Result' (NameError)
```

If the test passes, then the entire report is successful and I get the report summary. If only one test fails I get the error report above. I defined `test_transaction_should_be_valid` in my `transaction_test.rb` file and the proof of it is that it runs smoothly when the test passes.

I'm stuck on this now. Any ideas as to what might be causing this?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Apparently Rails is not yet quite compatible with Minitest 5.10/5.11:  https://github.com/seattlerb/minitest/issues/730  They have posted a monkeypatch to tide us over.

Rails has apparently also fixed this in edge.  https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/31624

This error disappeared for me when I pulled from the master branch.  Put this in your Gemfile:

```
gem 'rails', git: 'https://github.com/rails/rails.git'
```

**edit: promoting from comments** (thanks coco9nyc):

or you can try downgrading minitest:

```
gem 'minitest', '5.10.3'
```

Comment: By the way, in doing this, I also had to force `pg` to not upgrade to 1.0.0.:  `gem 'pg', '~> 0.21.0'`

Comment: I wish my Google searching had found this Github issue. Thank you!

Comment: you're welcome!  I googled this like a dog gnawing a bone, and finally got lucky.

Comment: The downgrading works for me. I've added another gem "activerecord-session_store" because of the command "rails test" suggestion.

Comment: Thanks, I'm in the middle of a Rails 4.2.8 to 5.0.7.x upgrade (on the way to 5.2.x) and encountered this. A smaller app that I skipped to Rails 5.2.6 did not encounter this bug.