# Rails 5.1.4 test throws NameError only when testing fails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, spring, railstutorial.org

When running rails test that fails, in a 5.1.4 rails app it throws the following NameError.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
27: from -e:1:in `<main>'
26: from /Users/User/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:59:in `require'
25: from /Users/User/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:59:in `require'
24: from /Users/User/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/application/boot.rb:19:in `<top (required)>'
23: from /Users/User/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/application.rb:135:in `run'
22: from /Users/User/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/application.rb:135:in `loop'
21: from /Users/User/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/application.rb:141:in `block in run'
20: from /Users/User/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/application.rb:171:in `serve'
19: from /Users/User/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/application.rb:171:in `fork'
18: from /Users/User/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0/gems/minitest-5.11.1/lib/minitest.rb:63:in `block in autorun'
17: from /Users/User/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0/gems/minitest-5.11.1/lib/minitest.rb:136:in `run'
16: from /Users/User/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0/gems/minitest-5.11.1/lib/minitest.rb:159:in `__run'
15: from /Users/User/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0/gems/minitest-5.11.1/lib/minitest.rb:159:in `map'
14: from /Users/User/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0/gems/minitest-5.11.1/lib/minitest.rb:159:in `block in __run'
13: from /Users/User/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/test_unit/line_filtering.rb:9:in `run'
12: from /Users/User/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0/gems/minitest-5.11.1/lib/minitest.rb:319:in `run'
11: from /Users/User/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0/gems/minitest-5.11.1/lib/minitest.rb:347:in `with_info_handler'
10: from /Users/User/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0/gems/minitest-5.11.1/lib/minitest.rb:360:in `on_signal'
 9: from /Users/User/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0/gems/minitest-5.11.1/lib/minitest.rb:320:in `block in run'
 8: from /Users/User/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0/gems/minitest-5.11.1/lib/minitest.rb:320:in `each'
 7: from /Users/User/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0/gems/minitest-5.11.1/lib/minitest.rb:321:in `block (2 levels) in run'
 6: from /Users/User/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0/gems/minitest-5.11.1/lib/minitest.rb:334:in `run_one_method'
 5: from /Users/User/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0/gems/minitest-5.11.1/lib/minitest.rb:785:in `record'
 4: from /Users/v/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0/gems/minitest-5.11.1/lib/minitest.rb:785:in `each'
 3: from /Users/User/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0/gems/minitest-5.11.1/lib/minitest.rb:786:in `block in record'
 2: from /Users/User/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/test_unit/reporter.rb:23:in `record'
 1: from /Users/User/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/test_unit/reporter.rb:70:in `format_rerun_snippet'
/Users/User/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/test_unit/reporter.rb:70:in `method': undefined method       `test_should_get_help' for class `Minitest::Result' (NameError)
```

However, if the test passes, the minitest report is shown without error messages at all.
I tried removing the minitest-reporters gem, but the NameError message does not go away.  Seems to be related to the spring server.
I also tried shutting down all spring ps.
Regarding **`test_should_get_help'** is a simple tests and despite deleting it, the error always puts the last written test in its place.

This is the Gemfile

```
    source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails',                   '5.1.4'
gem 'bcrypt',                  '3.1.11'
gem 'faker',                   '1.7.3'
gem 'carrierwave',             '1.2.2'
gem 'mini_magick',             '4.7.0'
gem 'will_paginate',           '3.1.6'
gem 'bootstrap-will_paginate', '1.0.0'
gem 'bootstrap-sass',          '3.3.7'
gem 'puma',                    '3.9.1'
gem 'sass-rails',              '5.0.6'
gem 'uglifier',                '3.2.0'
gem 'coffee-rails',            '4.2.2'
gem 'jquery-rails',            '4.3.1'
gem 'turbolinks',              '5.0.1'
gem 'jbuilder',                '2.7.0'

group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3', '1.3.13'
  gem 'byebug',  '9.0.6', platform: :mri
end

group :development do
  gem 'web-console',           '3.5.1'
  gem 'listen',                '3.1.5'
  gem 'spring',                '2.0.2'
  gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '2.0.1'
end

group :test do
  gem 'rails-controller-testing', '1.0.2'
  gem 'minitest-reporters',       '1.1.14'
  gem 'guard',                    '2.14.1'
  gem 'guard-minitest',           '2.4.6'
end

group :production do
  gem 'pg',  '0.20.0'
  gem 'fog', '1.42'
end

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found this thread: https://github.com/seattlerb/minitest/issues/730, which promises a fix to MiniTest. The fix will be available in a future Rails update, or now via Edge Rails.

I added a temporary entry to my `Gemfile` to revert MiniTest to the previous stable version,

```
# temporary fix to minitest 5.11.1 issue 
gem 'minitest', '~>5.10.3'
```

and then ran

```
bundle update minitest
```

It seems to work (but I'm still getting failed tests).

YMMV

Answer (score 0):

I found a temporary fix for this thanks to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48229515/rails-minitest-crashing-when-tests-fail)

I explicitely included the ministest gem and remove the minitest-reporters gem (have yet to verify if the problem persists with reporters included)

```
gem 'minitest', '5.10.3'
```

If you are working with pg in development, this might bring other errors.  The thread also suggested to pull the rails gem (in the gemfile) from git, this would avoid downgrading any gem.